# How to call store (vuex) on the the Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

How do I access the store on the Vue instance. Essentially, I and to do something like this:

```
Vue.store.dispatch('someAction')
```

or

```
Vue.$store.dispatch('someAction')
```

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Answer (score 1):

if you added vuex in your main.js
so you can do `this.$store.dispatch('someAction')`

also see [this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components) from vuex documentation